# Alternative to Tika/PDFBox for parsing PDF in Solr (any version later than 1.4)

Tags: solr, full-text-indexing, pdfbox, apache-tika, document-conversion

Seems like Solr is not parsing my PDF files correctly.  I was wondering if there is any other alternative to using Apache Tika (which I believe uses PDFBox internally) for parsing PDF files?  I seem to be getting random spaces in between my content when using this.  I have isolated the problem by running PDF through PDFBox directly (latest version) which has the same problem.

Some OCR commercial software such as Omnifind work on PDF fine but we are not able to integrate them with Solr in same way and buying is not an option either.

Comment: What version of Tika are you using?

Comment: I've tried with 0.10, I think 1.0 just came out, haven't tried that yet.  Will give it a shot tomorrow!  Thanks.

Comment: The PDFBox team are actively working on the project, and each new release tends to improve things, so it's worth trying a newer Tika+PDFBox to see if it helps

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, I tried with latest version of Tika 1.0 which I believe also uses latest version of PDFBox, it did improve things visibly when I used the new parameter they have added for turning off the auto spacing.  However, still not quite perfect on documents I am trying on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954788/pdfbox-adding-white-spaces-within-words) indicates, this is due to the nature of the PDF format itself.

It's possible that OCR options do better on this problem than PDFBox, there are some free OCR options available like [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) and [Ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) but I have no idea how well they work or if they can be easily integrated with Solr.

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but I am just trying and looking for alternatives so I can list which ones work best on what kind of documents.  I am not looking for perfect solution since I read that reply :)

Answer (score 1):

[Xpdf](http://foolabs.com/xpdf/home.html) contains pdftotext which converts documents a lot better then Tika.

Comment: can you go more into the details about what you mean by "a lot better"?

Answer (score 1):

I use [jpod](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpodlib/) as a fallback library to extract from pdf when pdfbox fails completely (hang, crash...), so at least in some cases it works better than pdbbox for me.