# How to get Document ids for Document Term Vector in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I am new to Lucene world, and don't have much working knowledge of the subject. I need to extract document term vector and I found the following code online [How to extract Document Term Vector in Lucene 3.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776794/how-to-extract-document-term-vector-in-lucene-3-5-0/8927749#8927749).

```
 /**
 * Sums the term frequency vector of each document into a single term frequency map
 * @param indexReader the index reader, the document numbers are specific to this reader
 * @param docNumbers document numbers to retrieve frequency vectors from
 * @param fieldNames field names to retrieve frequency vectors from
 * @param stopWords terms to ignore
 * @return a map of each term to its frequency
 * @throws IOException
 */
private Map<String,Integer> getTermFrequencyMap(IndexReader indexReader, List<Integer> docNumbers, String[] fieldNames, Set<String> stopWords)
throws IOException {
    Map<String,Integer> totalTfv = new HashMap<String,Integer>(1024);

    for (Integer docNum : docNumbers) {
        for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
            TermFreqVector tfv = indexReader.getTermFreqVector(docNum, fieldName);
            if (tfv == null) {
                // ignore empty fields
                continue;
            }

            String terms[] = tfv.getTerms();
            int termCount = terms.length;
            int freqs[] = tfv.getTermFrequencies();

            for (int t=0; t < termCount; t++) {
                String term = terms[t];
                int freq = freqs[t];

                // filter out single-letter words and stop words
                if (StringUtils.length(term) < 2 ||
                    stopWords.contains(term)) {
                    continue; // stop
                }

                Integer totalFreq = totalTfv.get(term);
                totalFreq = (totalFreq == null) ? freq : freq + totalFreq;
                totalTfv.put(term, totalFreq);
            }
        }
    }

    return totalTfv;
}
```

I have created the index which resides in the following directory.

```
String indexDir = "C:\\Lucene\\Output\\";
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(dir);
```

My problem is that I do not know how to get the doc ids (List docNumbers) which is required for the above mentioned function. I have tried a couple of methods like

```
TermDocs docs = reader.termDocs();
```

but it did not work.

Comment: btw, how come you know what's a term frequency vector and you don't know anything about lucene document ids?

Comment: @milan
I read that the Lucene does it automatically but the above code was a bit confusing as the "docNumbers" was passed as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene starts assigning ids from zero, and [maxDoc()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#maxDoc%28%29) is the upper limit, so you can simply loop to get all ids, skipping deleted documents (Lucene marks them for deletion when you call deleteDocument):

```
for (int docNum=0; docNum < reader.maxDoc(); docNum++) {
    if (reader.isDeleted(docNum)) {
        continue;
    }
    TermFreqVector tfv = reader.getTermFreqVector(docNum, "fieldName");
    ...
}
```

For this to work, you have to enable them during indexing, see [Field.TermVector](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.TermVector.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply

I have tried it already but it did not work.

Infact the problem was with the following line while creating index;

    <code>
    doc.add(new Field("contents", new FileReader(f));
    </code>
I have replaced it with the following line and it worked;
    <code>
    doc.add(new Field("contents", new FileReader(f),Field.TermVector.YES));
</code>