# How to retrive all terms with their frequency in that website

Tags: solr, lucene

I have indexed data of 10 websites in solr. Now i want to dump data of each website with following format : [Term,Frequency of terms in that website ,IDF,website]

```
e.g : [management,12,145,example.com] 
where 12 is a frequency of term in example.com, 145 is IDF of term in index.
```

Can i do this with solr and How?

Comment: Thanks you all for your responses : I have done that using facet query. where q=*:* and fq=host:myhost.com ,facet=true,facet.field=content, facet.limit=5000000

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to measure the the distribution of the distinct terms across the documents than histogram is what you want. Check [LukeRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) example.

Answer (score 0):

Some low-level API:

```
InderReader reader = IndexReader.open(directory);
TermDocs termDocs = reader.termDocs();   
// TermDocs termDocs = reader.termDocs(term);   //  if you need docs containing specific term
while (termDocs.next()) {
    System.out.println("Doc #: " + termDocs.doc());
    System.out.println("Full document: " + reader.document(termDocs.doc()));
    System.out.println("Term frequency: " + termDocs.freq());        
}
```

For tf*idf see [DefaultSimilarity](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/lucene/lucene-3.3.0/org/apache/lucene/search/DefaultSimilarity.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189179/extract-tf-idf-vectors-with-lucene) for some comments.