# SOLR: Create term vector (like data returned from TermVectorComponent) from raw text

Tags: solr

Using http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent I can get indexed terms and their frequencies for any document stored in my index. How can I get the same information for a text, without storing the text in my index? I just want SOLR to process the text and return the information, but without having to store the document in my index.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this isn't possible without storing data in SOLR.

If you are looking to do text analysis (I understand this is broader than what you ask for), I would recommend the below alternatives:

1. [MAUI](http://code.google.com/p/maui-indexer/) - does keyphrase and terminology extraction.
2. [Gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) - does topic modelling
3. [Kea](http://www.nzdl.org/Kea/) - keyword extraction

I've also come across some python scripts that do term frequency analysis. Have a look at [Mincemeat](https://github.com/michaelfairley/mincemeatpy), particulary the example, which does term frequency calculation.

Answer (score 1):

From what you ask for I conclude that you actually need a search library, not a full search engine (service). That library is Lucene. Perhaps, this will help for starters: [How to extract Document Term Vector in Lucene 3.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776794/how-to-extract-document-term-vector-in-lucene-3-5-0). You could store the index in RAM for the sake of computing necessary bits and then get rid of the index.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an application in Java several years ago that did heavy text analysis based on Lucene. I had to custom-write the search functions to find words within a certain distance of each other. You can import your text documents into the software and have it count the term frequencies, or you can take the code and taylor it to your needs.

Free download:
http://www.minoesoftware.com/download.php

Source:
https://github.com/danspiteri/MINOE/blob/master/src/minoe/SearchFiles.java

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Solr4 and you are not storing the text, you can use **a Solr pivot** on the text field. But then, obviously you will get terms after the analyzer processing:

```
http://192.168.0.202:8080/solr/fr_00_0425_sem/select?q=renault&wt=xml&facet=true&facet.pivot=uniqueKey,yourText
```

This is a pretty heavy query, I hope you don't have too many documents that match...