# How to prevent PDFBox from splitting words with hyphen

Tags: c#, pdfbox, hyphenation

I'm using PDFBox version 1.7.0 to extract text from a PDF. The classes were compiled to .NET using `IKVM.NET`. I'm using the following code, where I pass in the name and path to the file:

```
public static String PDFText(String PDFFilePath)
    {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(PDFFilePath);
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        string text = stripper.getText(doc);
        doc.close();
        return text;
    }
```

The PDF has 2-columns throughout.
The extraction works fairly well. However, many words are being split over to the next line by a hyphen where they should be preserved as a complete word.

For example, the word "becoming" changes to "becom-
ing" as do many other words.

Is there a way to prevent PDFBox from randomly splitting a word with a dash "-" or hyphen and displaying part of the word on one line while carrying the rest of it to the next line?

I saw an article on stackoverflow that dealt with inserting white spaces between words randomly, i.e. [PDFBox adding white spaces within words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954788/pdfbox-adding-white-spaces-within-words/7956950#7956950).

However, my issue is PDFBox splitting with dashes or hyphens.

I also saw reference to a method called `charactersByArticle`, which was expressly for twocolumn PDFs and I thought perhaps this might render the extracted text correctly. However, I have not found a working example of how to use this method, just teaser references to it.

If the `charactersByArticle` method wouldn't prevent this, I would even consider Regex if someone could provide a good working example of using this in conjunction with my PDFTextStripper method above. Thank you in advance.